# Video Background Full Screen in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, fullscreen

I am working on a website hobbinternational.com, and I need the video in the home page to cover the whole screen and the header to be transparent. I tried a lot but couldnt find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed;` into `.page-header`

For others, here is an example of a video in the background

```css
.bg-video-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://designsupply-web.com/samplecontent/vender/codepen/20181014.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
}
video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.7) 50%);
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-video-wrap">
    <video src="https://designsupply-web.com/samplecontent/vender/codepen/20181014.mp4" loop muted autoplay>
    </video>
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
    <h1>Fullscreen video background
    </h1>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/designsupply/pen/zmEWBm